# Hack machine language assembler as required for project 6 of Nand2Tetris

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers, assembly

[This](https://github.com/pillboxer/Assembler) is the implementation of the Assembler required to parse source code written in the [Hack Machine Language](https://zhangruochi.com/Machine-Language/2019/09/22/#the-hack-language-specification) and output it to a 16-bit binary file.

After writing one go in Swift, I decided I wanted to give it a go writing it in C as a challenge to myself to become more comfortable with the language as well as taking the opportunity to write my own hash table.

I'd love any feedback on any aspect of the code but I'm particularly looking for areas of improvement with regards to pointers and memory management. I don't believe Valgrind is supported on M1 Mac machines, therefore the memory allocation and deallocation was written somewhat blind.

I'd also appreciate any pointers (no pun intended) on how I can improve adherence to C conventions.

**Assembler.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "error/Error.h"
#include "components/Stripper.h"
#include "components/Parser.h"

#define MAX_ASSEMBLED_SIZE 1048576

static void assemble(const char *file, char *output_name);

// Entry point for program
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    switch (argc) {
        case 2:
            // No file name specified - revert to "assembled.hack"
            assemble(argv[1], NULL);
            break;
        case 3:
            // Use client-specified file name
            assemble(argv[1], argv[2]);
            break;
        default:
            // ❌
            exit_with_error(INCORRECT_ARGUMENT_COUNT);      
    }
    return 0;

}

// Assembles a file into binary code
static void assemble(const char *file_name, char *output_name) {

    long size_in_bytes;
    char* file_to_assemble;
    printf("Starting assembly of file %s\n", file_name);
    
    // Check if the file exists
    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        exit_with_error(FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    else {

        // Create a HashMap to store variables and label definitions
        HashMap* hash_map = hash_map_create();

        // Retrieve the size of the file (max 500k)
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        size_in_bytes = ftell(file);

        if (size_in_bytes > MAX_ASSEMBLED_SIZE / 2) {
            exit_with_error(FILE_TOO_LARGE);
        }
        
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); 
        file_to_assemble = malloc(size_in_bytes + 1);

        if (file_to_assemble) {
            
            // Read the contents of the file into the buffer
            fread(file_to_assemble, 1, size_in_bytes, file);
            char no_comments[size_in_bytes + 1];
            char no_spaces[size_in_bytes + 1];
            char no_labels[size_in_bytes + 1];
            char parsed[MAX_ASSEMBLED_SIZE + 1];
            
            // Remove comments and blank spaces. Save and remove labels, save variables
            strip_comments(no_comments, file_to_assemble);
            strip_spaces(no_spaces, no_comments);
            strip_labels(no_labels, no_spaces, hash_map);
            save_variables(no_labels, hash_map);

            // Translate the remaining assembly code to binary
            parse(parsed, no_labels, hash_map);

            char output_file_name[256];

            // If the client chose a custom output name
            if (output_name != NULL) {
                strcpy(output_file_name, output_name);
            }
            else {
                strcpy(output_file_name, "assembled.hack");
            }
            
            // Write the file
            FILE *output = fopen(output_file_name, "w");
            fwrite(parsed, 1, strlen(parsed), output);
            fclose(file);
            hash_map_free(hash_map);
            printf("Assembly complete");
        }
        else {
            // Could not open file. Bail
            exit_with_error(FILE_READ_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**Stripper.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "HashMap.h"
#include "Parser.h"

#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 16384
#define KBD_ADDRESS 24576
#define SP_ADDRESS 0
#define LCL_ADDRESS 1
#define ARG_ADDRESS 2
#define THIS_ADDRESS 3
#define THAT_ADDRESS 4

// Removes extraneous white space and blank lines
void strip_spaces (char* dst, const char* src) {

    bool have_reached_printable_char = false;
    int count = 0;
    int length = strlen(src);

    while(*src != '\0') {
        if (count == length - 1 && *src == '\n')
            break;
        have_reached_printable_char = have_reached_printable_char ? true : isprint(*src);
        if(have_reached_printable_char && (*src == '\n' || !isspace(*src))) {
            *dst = *src; // then copy
            dst++;
        }
        count++;
        src++;
    }

    *dst = '\0';
}

// Remove comments (like this!) from file
void strip_comments(char* dst, const char* src) {

    bool copy = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++) {
        if (src[i] == '\n')
            copy = true;
        if (src[i] == '/' && src[i+1] == '/')
            copy = false;
        if (copy) {
            *dst = src[i];
            dst++;
        }
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}

// Map particular variables to corresponding address
static void map_reserved_variables(HashMap* hash_map) {
    
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "screen", SCREEN_ADDRESS);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "kbd", KBD_ADDRESS);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "sp", SP_ADDRESS);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "lcl", LCL_ADDRESS);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "arg", ARG_ADDRESS);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "this", THIS_ADDRESS);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, "that", THAT_ADDRESS);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        int length = i < 10 ? 2 : 3;
        char reg[length + 1];
        reg[0] = 'r';
        sprintf(reg + 1, "%d", i);
        hash_map_put(hash_map, reg, i);
    }
}

    

// Remove label definitions and replace them with corresponding line number of
// logic following the definition
void strip_labels(char* dst, const char* src, HashMap* hash_map) {

    map_reserved_variables(hash_map);

    int current_command = 0;
    bool save_command = false;
    bool new_command = true;
    bool copy = true;
    char current_label[256];
    int current_label_index = 0;
    char last_copied;

    while(*src != '\0') {
        if (*src == '\n') {
            new_command = true;
            if (last_copied == '\n') {
                src++;
            }
            current_command++;
            copy = true;
        }

        if (*src == ')' && save_command) {  
            save_command = false;
            current_label[current_label_index] = '\0';
            // Move backwards to go back to the command we were dealing with
            current_command--;
            for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(current_label); i++) {
                char lowered = tolower(current_label[i]);
                current_label[i] = lowered;
            }
            // Now move forward one line and save whatever command number that is
            hash_map_put(hash_map, current_label, current_command+1);
            current_label_index = 0;
        }
        if (save_command) {
            current_label[current_label_index++] = *src;
        }
        if (new_command && *src == '(') {
            save_command = true;
            copy = false;
        }       
        if (copy) {
            *dst = *src;
            dst++;
            last_copied = *src;
        }
        src++;
    }
        *dst = '\0';
}

// Save any user declared variables
void save_variables(char* dst, HashMap* hash_map) {
    bool is_a_variable_declaration = false;
    char current_variable[256];
    int current_variable_index = 0;
    int current_variable_address = 16;

    while(*dst != '\0') {

        if (*dst == '\n') {
            if (is_a_variable_declaration) {
                is_a_variable_declaration = false;
                current_variable[current_variable_index] = '\0';
                current_variable_index = 0;

                if (!is_integral_string(current_variable)) {
                    if (hash_map_contains(hash_map, current_variable)) {
                        // It's a label declaration that we've already saved in the method above
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        hash_map_put(hash_map, current_variable, current_variable_address++);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (is_a_variable_declaration) {
            current_variable[current_variable_index++] = tolower(*dst);
        }
        if (*dst == '@') {
            char next = tolower(*(++dst));
            if (next != 'r' && next != '0') {
                is_a_variable_declaration = true;
            }
            dst--;
        }
        dst++;
    }
}
```

**Parser.c**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "HashMap.h"
#include "Parser.h"
#include "../error/Error.h"

#define VALID_DESTINATION_COUNT 7
#define VALID_COMPUTATION_COUNT 28
#define VALID_JUMP_COUNT 7
#define WORD_LENGTH 16

#define A_START 0

#define C_A_OR_M_START 3
#define C_A_OR_M_BIT_LENGTH 1

#define C_DEFAULTS_START 0
#define C_DEFAULTS_BIT_LENGTH 3
#define C_DEFAULTS_ADDRESS 7

#define C_COMP_START 4
#define C_COMP_BIT_LENGTH 6

#define C_JUMP_START 13
#define C_JUMP_BIT_LENGTH 3

#define C_DEST_BIT_LENGTH 3
#define C_DEST_START 10

// Declarations

static bool is_a_command(const char* str); 

static int jump_address(const char* str);
static int destination_address(const char* str);
static int get_computation_address(const char* cmd);
static int get_jump_address(const char* cmd, int jump_operation_position); 
static int get_destination_address(const char* cmd, int assignment_operation_position);

static void parse_c_command(char* dst, const char* cmd);
static void parse_command(char* dst, const char *cmd, HashMap* hash_map); 
static void parse_a_command(char* dst, const char* cmd, HashMap* hash_map); 
static void to_bin(char* cmd, int address, int number_of_places, int starting_position); 
static void get_positions(const char* cmd, int* assignment, int* computation, int *termination, int* jump); 


// *********** CONSTANTS ************** //

// Allowed destinations in C instruction
const char* valid_destinations[VALID_DESTINATION_COUNT] = { "M", "D", "MD", "A", "AM", "AD", "AMD" };
// Allowed computations in C instruction
const char* valid_computations[VALID_COMPUTATION_COUNT] = { "0", "1", "-1", "D", "A", "!D", "!A", "-D", 
                                                            "-A", "D+1", "A+1", "D-1", "A-1", "D+A", "D-A", 
                                                            "A-D", "D&A", "D|A", "M", "!M", "-M", "M+1", 
                                                            "M-1", "D+M", "D-M", "M-D", "D&M", "D|M" };
// Denary representation of a valid computation. 
// For example the instruction D|M (see above) corresponds to 21 -> (101001)
const int valid_computation_integers[VALID_COMPUTATION_COUNT] = { 42, 63, 58, 12, 48, 13, 49, 15, 
                                                                    51, 31, 55, 14, 50, 2, 19,
                                                                    7, 0, 21, 48, 49, 51, 
                                                                    55, 50, 2, 19, 7, 0, 21 }; 
// Allowed jump commands in C instruction
const char* valid_jumps[VALID_JUMP_COUNT] = { "JGT", "JEQ", "JGE", "JLT", "JNE", "JLE", "JMP" };


// *********** PARSING ************** //

// Parse a source asm file that has been stripped of whitespace and comments
void parse(char* dst, char* src, HashMap* hash_map) {

    char current_label[256];
    int current_label_position = 0;
    int dest_position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(src); i++) {
    
        if (src[i] == '\n' || src[i] == '\0') {
            // We've either reached a line break or EOF
            current_label[current_label_position] = '\0';
            char parsed[WORD_LENGTH + 1];
            to_bin(parsed, 0, WORD_LENGTH, 0);
            parsed[WORD_LENGTH] = '\0';
            // Parse the current command
            parse_command(parsed, current_label, hash_map);
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(parsed); j++) {
                // Add the newly parsed command to the output file
                dst[dest_position++] = parsed[j];   
            }
            // Reset label posiion and add \n or \0 to output
            current_label_position = 0;
            dst[dest_position++] = src[i];
            continue;
        }
        current_label[current_label_position++] = src[i];
    }
    // Done, make sure to end with null terminator
    dst[dest_position] = '\0';
}

static void parse_command(char* dst, const char *cmd, HashMap* hash_map) {

    // Can either be A command ("@command") or C command ("D=D+1;JGE")
    if (is_a_command(cmd)) {
        parse_a_command(dst, cmd, hash_map);
    }
    else {
        parse_c_command(dst, cmd);
    }
}

static void parse_c_command(char* dst, const char* cmd) {

    int assignment_operation_position = 0;
    int computation_operation_position = 0;
    int jump_operation_position = 0;
    int computation_termination_position = 0;

    // Fill in parts of parsed command that are common to all C instructions
    to_bin(dst, C_DEFAULTS_ADDRESS, C_DEFAULTS_BIT_LENGTH, C_DEFAULTS_START);
    get_positions(cmd, &assignment_operation_position, &computation_operation_position, &computation_termination_position, &jump_operation_position);

    // Split the command into destination (if applicable), computation and jump (if applicable)

    if (assignment_operation_position != 0) {
        int address = get_destination_address(cmd, assignment_operation_position);
        if (address == -1) {
            exit_with_error(MALFORMED_DESTINATION);
        }
        else { 
            to_bin(dst, address, C_DEST_BIT_LENGTH, C_DEST_START);
        }
    }

    int computation_string_length = computation_termination_position - computation_operation_position;
    char computation_string[computation_string_length + 1];
    strncpy(computation_string, cmd+computation_operation_position, computation_string_length);
    computation_string[computation_string_length] = '\0';
    int computation_address = get_computation_address(computation_string);

    if (computation_address == -1) {
        exit_with_error(MALFORMED_COMPUTATION);
    }
    else {
        to_bin(dst, computation_address, C_COMP_BIT_LENGTH, C_COMP_START);
        for (int i = computation_operation_position; i < computation_termination_position; i++) {
            if (tolower(cmd[i]) == 'm') {
                to_bin(dst, 1, C_A_OR_M_BIT_LENGTH, C_A_OR_M_START);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (jump_operation_position != 0) {
        int address = get_jump_address(cmd, jump_operation_position);
        if (address == -1) {
            exit_with_error(MALFORMED_JUMP);
        }
        else {
            to_bin(dst, address, C_JUMP_BIT_LENGTH, C_JUMP_START);
        }
    }
}

static void parse_a_command(char* dst, const char* cmd, HashMap* hash_map) {

    size_t cmd_length = strlen(cmd);
    char lowered[cmd_length];
    int index = 0;

    // Disregard '@' by starting at index 1
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= cmd_length; i++) {
        lowered[index++] = tolower(cmd[i]);
    }
    if (!is_integral_string(lowered)) {
        // It's a user-declared variable
        int value = hash_map_get(hash_map, lowered);
        to_bin(dst, value, WORD_LENGTH, A_START);
    }
    else {
        // It's a direct address (eg '@42')
        char address_string[cmd_length];
        strncpy(address_string, lowered, cmd_length);
        int address = atoi(address_string);
        to_bin(dst, address, WORD_LENGTH, A_START);
    }   
}


// *********** ADDRESSES ************** //

// Retreive generic address from array
static int get_address(const char* str, const char** argv, unsigned int count) {

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(str, argv[i]) == 0) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// Retrieve destination address from C instruction
static int get_destination_address(const char* cmd, int assignment_operation_position) {

    char destination[assignment_operation_position + 1];
    strncpy(destination, cmd, assignment_operation_position);
    destination[assignment_operation_position] = '\0';
    return destination_address(destination);
}

static int destination_address(const char* str) {
    return get_address(str, valid_destinations, VALID_DESTINATION_COUNT);
}

// Retrieve computation address from C instruction
static int get_computation_address(const char* cmd) {

    for (int i = 0; i < VALID_COMPUTATION_COUNT; i++) {
        if (strcmp(valid_computations[i], cmd) == 0) {
            return valid_computation_integers[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// Retrieve jump address from C instruction
static int get_jump_address(const char* cmd, int jump_operation_position) {

    int jump_operation_length = strlen(cmd) - jump_operation_position;
    char jump_operation[jump_operation_length + 1];
    strncpy(jump_operation, cmd+jump_operation_position, jump_operation_length);
    jump_operation[jump_operation_length] = '\0';
    return jump_address(jump_operation);

} 

static int jump_address(const char* str) {
   return get_address(str, valid_jumps, VALID_JUMP_COUNT);
}


// *********** HELPER ************** //

static bool is_a_command(const char* str) {
    return str[0] == '@' && strlen(str) > 1;
}

// Is the command pure integers?
bool is_integral_string(char *str) {

    size_t length = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Retrieve positions of assignment, computation, 
// and jump instructions as well as the point of termination of a computation
static void get_positions(const char* cmd, int* assignment, int* computation, int *termination, int* jump) {

    size_t length = strlen(cmd);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (cmd[i] == '=') {
            *assignment = i;
            *computation = i+1;
        }
        if (cmd[i] == ';') {
            *jump = i+1;
            *termination = i;
        }
    }
    if (*termination == 0) {
        *termination = length;
    }
}

// Convert an address to binary padding with number of places, 
// starting (0 being the 'end' of the string) at starting_position
static void to_bin(char* cmd, int address, int number_of_places, int starting_position) {

    int quo = address;
    int index = number_of_places + starting_position - 1;

    int rem;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_places; i++) {
        rem = quo % 2;
        cmd[index--] = rem == 1 ? '1' : '0';
        quo = quo / 2;
    }
}
```

**HashMap.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "HashMap.h"

// Hashing function, courtesy of
// http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
static int hashed(char* arg) {

    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while ((c = *arg++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; 
    return hash % NUM_BUCKETS;
}

// Create a HashMap (caller to free) 
HashMap* hash_map_create() {
    HashMap *hash_map = malloc(sizeof(HashMap));
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUCKETS; i++)
        hash_map->buckets[i] = NULL;
    return hash_map;
}

// Insert into HashMap (assumes non-negative value)
void hash_map_put(HashMap* hash_map, char* key, int value) {

    int hashed_key = hashed(key);
    int result = hash_map_get(hash_map, key);

    if (result != -1) {
        // Overwrite old value
        Node *current = hash_map->buckets[hashed_key];
        while (current->key != key) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->value = value;
    }
    else {
        if (hash_map->buckets[hashed_key] == NULL) {
            // Insert at first node in bucket
            hash_map->buckets[hashed_key] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            hash_map->buckets[hashed_key]->key =  malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(key) + 1));
            strcpy(hash_map->buckets[hashed_key]->key, key);
            hash_map->buckets[hashed_key]->value = value;
            hash_map->buckets[hashed_key]->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            // Collision, traverse to end of linked list
            Node *current = hash_map->buckets[hashed_key];
            Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            new->key = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(key) + 1));
            strcpy(new->key, key);
            new->value = value;
            new->next = NULL;
            while (current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = new;
        }
    }
}

bool hash_map_contains(HashMap* hash_map, char* key) {
    return hash_map_get(hash_map, key) != -1;
}

// Retrieve value for key from HashMap
int hash_map_get(HashMap* hash_map, char* key) {

    int hashed_key = hashed(key);
    Node *current = hash_map->buckets[hashed_key];
    int returned = -1;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->key, key) == 0) {
            returned = current->value;
            break;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return returned;
}

// Remove value for key in HashMap
void hash_map_remove(HashMap* hash_map, char* key) {

    int hashed_key = hashed(key);
    if (hash_map_get(hash_map, key) != -1) {
        Node *current = hash_map->buckets[hashed_key];
        if (current->key == key) {
            // Remove from head node
            Node *new_current = current->next;
            current = NULL;
            hash_map->buckets[hashed_key] = new_current;
        }
        else {
            // Traverse and remove when found
            while (current->next->key != key) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            Node *old_next = current->next;
            Node *new_next = current->next->next;
            current->next = new_next;
            old_next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

// Free HashMap
void hash_map_free(HashMap* hash_map) {
    free(hash_map);
}
```

**Error.c**

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Error.h"

void error_string_for_code(int code, char **star);

void exit_with_error(int code) {
    char *str = "";
    error_string_for_code(code, &str);
    printf("Exiting with error: '%s'\n", str);
    exit(code);
}

void error_string_for_code(int code, char **str) {
    
    switch (code) {
        case INCORRECT_ARGUMENT_COUNT:
            *str = "Incorrect argument count";
            break;
        case FILE_NOT_FOUND:
            *str = "The file doesn't exist";
            break;
        case FILE_READ_ERROR:
            *str = "Could not read file";
            break;
        case NULL_POINTER:
            *str = "Null pointer found";
            break; 
        case UNKNOWN_COMMAND:
            *str = "Unrecognized command";
            break;
        case MALFORMED_DESTINATION:
            *str = "Invalid destination received";
            break;
        case MALFORMED_COMPUTATION:
            *str = "Received a missing computation";
            break;
        case MALFORMED_JUMP:
            *str = "Invalid jump received";
            break;
        case FILE_TOO_LARGE:
            *str = "File too large, please ensure it is less than 500kb";
            break;
        default:
            *str = "Unknown error.";
        break;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks to both reviewers for their thorough answers. Working through the recommended changes [here](https://github.com/pillboxer/Assembler/issues/17)

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Fix the bug

In `assemble()` the file is read with `fread` which is appropriate, but later when the buffer is being processed to strip comments, the code makes the invalid assumption that the buffer is terminated with a `NUL` character.  To fix that, explicitly terminate the string:

```
// Read the contents of the file into the buffer
fread(file_to_assemble, 1, size_in_bytes, file);
// assure the buffer is terminated
file_to_assemble[size_in_bytes] = '\0';
```

### Don't leak memory

The `hash_map_free()` function frees the overall `HashMap` but fails to free the memory of each of the `Node`'s `key` and `*next` values.  Likewise within `hash_map_remove`, the removed node pointer is set to `NULL` which is fine, but the memory is not freed which is not fine.  Here's one way to rewrite `hash_map_free()`:

```
void hash_map_free(HashMap* hash_map) {
    if (hash_map) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUCKETS; ++i) {
            for (Node* curr = hash_map->buckets[i]; curr; ) {
                Node* victim = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                free(victim->key);
                free(victim);
            }
        }
    }
    free(hash_map);
}
```

Similarly, you'll have to make the corresponding changes in `hash_map_remove`.

### Understand C idiom

The `strip_comments` function works, but it uses an indexed variable `s[i]` instead of a plain pointer.  Here's an alternative version that skips the call to `strlen` and mostly avoids the use of indexing.

```
void strip_comments(char* dst, const char* src) {
    for (bool copy = true; *src; ++src) {
        if (*src == '\n') {
            copy = true;
        }
        else if (*src == '/' && src[1] == '/') {
            copy = false;
        }
        if (copy) {
            *dst++ = *src;
        }
    }
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

Other enhancements are to use `else` since both statements are mutually exclusive and to add `{}` to each clause for safety.  Also, this code uses another very common idiom: `*dst++ = *src;`.

### Use consistent formatting

In the `Stripper.c` file, the formatting of the three functions is slightly different.  It helps the reader if the formatting is consistent.

### Simplify expressions

The `strip_spaces` function currently has this line:

```
have_reached_printable_char = have_reached_printable_char ? true : isprint(*src);
```

It looks a bit peculiar to me and took me a moment to see what it was doing.  I think a clearer way of doing this would be this:

```
have_reached_printable_char |= isprint(*src);
```

### Use `const` where practical

Many of the functions correctly use `const` as part of their signatures, which is good.  More can be done, however, such as declaring `length` within `strip_spaces()` as `const`.

### Prefer `for` to `while` where practical

The `strip_spaces` function has a `while` loop that I think would be better written as a `for` loop.  The `for` loop has the advantages that the scope of `count` is reduced to only within the loop (scope reduction is good because it both helps the compiler allocate registers and makes it easier for humans to understand) and it makes clear which values are unconditionally updated each loop.  In this case, I'd write it like this:

```
for (int count = 0; *src != '\0'; ++count, ++src) {
```

### Simplify your functions

The `for` loop within `map_reserved_variables` is a bit more complex than it needs to be.  First, we don't really care how large the buffer is as long as it has the capacity to store the maximum size register name.  Second, the name always starts with `r`.  We can simplify by writing the loop like this:

```
char reg_name[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    snprintf(reg_name, 5, "r%d", i);
    hash_map_put(hash_map, reg_name, i);
}
```

Note also the use of `snprintf` for additional safety.

### Reduce the use of "magic numbers"

There are a few numbers in the code, such as `16` and `256` that have a specific meaning in their particular context.  By using named constants such as `NUM_REGISTERS` or `MAX_LABEL_SIZE`, the program becomes easier to read and maintain.  Also, it's generally better to use `const int` than `#define` for numeric values.

### Use `struct` to associate related items

During parsing, the `get_computation_address()` function is called.  It's currently like this:

```
static int get_computation_address(const char* cmd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < VALID_COMPUTATION_COUNT; i++) {
        if (strcmp(valid_computations[i], cmd) == 0) {
            return valid_computation_integers[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It relies on three separate things, `VALID_COMPUTATION_COUNT` which is a constant, `valid_computations` which is an array of command strings, and `valid_computation_integers` which is an array of numbers associated with each command.  Instead of three separate items with only a loose binding among them, I'd suggest using a `struct`:

```
const struct computation {
    const char *text;
    int value;
} Computations[] = {
    { "0", 42 }, { "1", 63 }, { "-1", 58 }, { "D", 12 }, { "A", 48 }, 
    { "!D", 13 }, { "!A", 49 }, { "-D", 15 }, { "-A", 51 }, {"D+1", 31 }, 
    {"A+1", 55 }, {"D-1", 14 }, {"A-1", 50 }, {"D+A", 2 }, {"D-A", 19 },
    { "A-D", 7 }, {"D&A", 0 }, {"D|A", 21 }, {"M", 48 }, {"!M", 49 }, 
    {"-M", 51 }, {"M+1", 55 }, { "M-1", 50 }, {"D+M", 2 }, {"D-M", 19 }, 
    {"M-D", 7 }, {"D&M", 0 }, {"D|M", 21 },
    { NULL, -1 }  // end of list
};
```

The corresponding code is also simple:

```
static int get_computation_address(const char* cmd) {
    const struct computation* comp = Computations;
    for ( ; comp->text && strcmp(cmd, comp->text) != 0; ++comp) {
    }
    return comp->value;
}
```

Now it's easy for a human to see the associated mnemonics and values and no explicit count is needed because a sentinel value is used instead.

### Simplify instruction creation

Right now there are a lot of calls to `to_bin` which does all sorts of work getting values into the right location for the final instruction.  Instead, why not just compute in binary and use a bitwise-or operation to assemble the instruction?  An example, if we have the values for `a`, `comp`, `dest` and `jmp`, we can easily construct a C-instruction:

```
int inst = 0xE000 | (a << 12) | (comp << 6) | (dest << 3) | jmp;
```

Even better, since the values of `a` and `comp` are implicit from the mnemonic, we could use the table structure above to contain both and put them into the table as the value we'll need *already shifted into place*.  So the table would be:

```
const struct computation {
    const char *text;
    int value;
} Computations[] = {
    { "0", 42<<6 }, { "1", 63<<6 }, { "-1", 58<<6 }, { "D", 12<<6 }, { "A", 48<<6 }, 
    { "!D", 13<<6 }, { "!A", 49<<6 }, { "-D", 15<<6 }, { "-A", 51<<6 }, {"D+1", 31<<6 }, 
    {"A+1", 55<<6 }, {"D-1", 14<<6 }, {"A-1", 50<<6 }, {"D+A", 2<<6 }, {"D-A", 19<<6 },
    { "A-D", 7<<6 }, {"D&A", 0<<6 }, {"D|A", (64|21)<<6 }, {"M", (64|48)<<6 }, {"!M", (64|49)<<6 }, 
    {"-M", (64|51)<<6 }, {"M+1", (64|55)<<6 }, { "M-1", (64|50)<<6 }, {"D+M", (64|2)<<6 }, {"D-M", (64|19)<<6 }, 
    {"M-D", (64|7)<<6 }, {"D&M", (64|0)<<6 }, {"D|M", (64|21)<<6 },
    { NULL, -1 }  // end of list
};
```

Now we can fetch the value directly from here, use `|` to compose the instruction in binary and convert to an ASCII string once.

### Simplify conversion to ASCII

A small, simple way to convert a 16-bit `int` into binary is like this:

```
for (int mask = 0x8000; mask; mask >>= 1) {
    *dst++ = (mask & instruction) ? '1' : '0';
}
```

### Avoid copying strings

In the `parse` command, instead of parsing to a temporary string and then copying from there to the destination, why not just put it directly in place?  Here's a rewrite that shows how this might look:

```
void parse(char* dst, const char* src, HashMap* hash_map) {
    static char label_buffer[256];
    char *current_label = label_buffer;

    for (bool working = true ; working; ++src) {
        if (*src == '\n' || *src == '\0') {
            // We've either reached a line break or EOF
            *current_label = '\0';
            // Parse the current command
            parse_command(dst, label_buffer, hash_map);
            dst += WORD_LENGTH;
            // Reset label posiion and add \n or \0 to output
            current_label = label_buffer;
            *dst++ = *src;
            working = *src;
        } else {
            *current_label++ = *src;
        }
    }
    // Done, make sure to end with null terminator
    *dst = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I'm so grateful for this. I'm in the process of making the changes. My test suite is failing when making your last change (**Avoid copying strings**) - the `current_label` appears to have garbage values in it, although `label_buffer` is correct. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Make sure you are passing `label_buffer` to `parse_command` and not `current_label`.

Comment: I am; did a direct copy-paste... I'll keep investigating!

Answer (score 4):

## Alternatives to Valgrind for memory allocation checking

> I don't believe Valgrind is supported on M1 Mac machines, therefore the memory allocation and deallocation was written somewhat blind.

Luckily there are other ways to check whether you have memory leaks. In particular, Clang includes support for the [AddressSanitizier](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html). Compile and link your program with `fsanitize=address`, and then it will print out any leaks and other potential issues at runtime.

## Avoid unnecessary forward declarations

You can avoid forward declaration by changing the order in which functions are defined in your source files. This way, you don't have to repeat yourself, and if you change the function name or parameters, you only have to do it in one place.

## Reporting errors

It's nice to have a single function that prints an error and exits the program with a non-zero exit code. There are a few problems with your implementation though.

First, ensure you write error messages to `stderr`. This ensures they don't get mingled with regular output written to `stdout`, which is especially important if output is redirected. Furthermore, I recommend you use [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) as the exit code for all errors. Other values are non-standard.

Also, having to maintain a list of enums and their corresponding error messages is a bit of work, and it's not very flexible. I recommend you either use the BSD function [`err()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/err) or reimplement it yourself. This way, you can report errors like so:

```
if (size_in_bytes > MAX_ASSEMBLED_SIZE / 2) {
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "File too large, make sure it is less than %d bytes", MAX_ASSEMBLED_SIZE / 2);
}
```

## Consider allowing input from `stdin` and output to `stdout`

Instead of always reading from a file and writing the result to another file, consider allowing `stdin` and `stdout` to be used. This allows your assembler to be used in more complicated command lines, where for example the assembly is generated by one program and can then be piped directly into your assembler. This is quite normal on any UNIX-like operating system, but even Windows supports input and output redirection like that.

In particular, if the program is called with zero arguments, read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`. If it is called with one argument, read from the provided filename and write to `stdout`.

Also ensure you don't print any diagnostics to `stdout` where it could get mingled with the assembly output. Use `stderr` for any progress updates, or consider just not printing any information at all if things go well.

## Unnecessary file size limitation?

I see the Hack machine language supports 32 bit pointers so it should be able to address up to 4 GB. I think the reason you limit the maximum assembled size to 1 megabyte is because you are allocating potentially very large arrays on the stack in `assemble()`. Use `malloc()` for to allocate those arrays instead, that way you don't exhaust the limited amount of stack space.

## Give correct error messages

If `malloc()` fails, your program currently prints the error message "Could not read file", which is misleading. Make sure error messages clearly describe the actual error that occurred.

## Avoid arbitrary limits for filenames

You declare the string `output_file_name` as an array of 256 `char`s. But filenames can be longer than that. Don't assume any limit. Either use [`strdup()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) (which unfortunately is not standard C *yet*), or `malloc(strlen(...) + 1)`, or even better avoid having to allocate anything at all:

```
FILE *output = fopen(output_name ? output_name : "assembled.hack", "w");
```

## Missing error checking

I/O errors can happen at any time, not just when opening a file. Check the return value of `fread()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`, and make sure you report an error to `stderr` and exit the program with `EXIT_FAILURE` in case there was an error.

Furthermore, there are several calls to `malloc()` in the code where the return value is not checked.

## Reducing the number of passes over the input

You are processing the input several times, each time doing one thing, like removing comments. This takes time, and you are also using a lot of temporary storage space for each pass. Ideally, you would parse everything in a single pass.

Parsing the input in a single pass can be done by changing the bookkeeping of labels. Parse each line, strip spaces and comments. If anything is remaining, check if it's a variable or label. If it's a reference to a label you have seen defined before, you can just immediately substitute it by its line number. Otherwise, you have to remember that you have to insert the line number here when you reach the line where the label is defined. When you encounter a label definition, check if you have to fix up any line numbers in earlier output.

## Naming things

"Stripper.c"  might not be the best choice of a file name, especially if it does more than just stripping things: it also deals with variables.

I think you did a great job with the function and variables names. Some minor issues:

- `dst` in `save_variables()` should probably be renamed to `src`, and be made `const` while you are at it.
- In the forward declaration of `error_string_for_code()`, `star` should be `str`.

## Correct use of `tolower()` and `isdigit()`

The functions from `<ctype.h>` expect an `int` as the argument, not a `char`. Also, they expect the value to be greater than or equal to zero for all valid characters. The correct way to use them is to cast the `char` to `unsigned char` before using it as an argument, like so:

```
if (!isdigit((unsigned char)str[i])) {
    return false;
}
```

## Prefer `strtol()` over `atoi()`

Use [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead of `atoi()`, and use the second argument to check that the whole number was read correctly.

## Better way to pass sizes to `malloc()`

Instead of:

```
Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

It is generally preferred to write:

```
Node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
```

This avoids having to repeat the type twice. Furthermore, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C standard, so instead of:

```
new->key = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(key) + 1));
```

You can just write:

```
new->key = malloc(strlen(key) + 1);
```

## Memory leak when freeing the hash map

`hash_map_free()` only frees the array of pointers to buckets, not the contents of the buckets themselves.

Comment: Thanks for this, G. Slowly implementing these changes. Appreciate the heads up about `fsanitize=address` - I do indeed have memory issues!